# How does SCORM handle navigation between lessons?

Tags: scorm, scorm2004, scorm1.2

i would like to manually create a scorm package, to understand the mechanisms.
I have read about content packaging and run time on the [scorm website.](https://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/)

The content packaging is easy to understand but i have problems with the tasks of the run-time environment.

I understand that the scorm package display a html page with the desired content and communicate (initialize, commit, ...) with the LMS over the scorm API to persist data.

But how can i navigate to another lesson?
Should my run-time environment navigate between lessons or is the LMS concerned to navigate between the lessons?

I have read that some scorm generators like iSpring includes a front end user interface with navigation. But it sounds like this is optional.

Also i don't understand the entire scorm terminology. In an LMS i have courses (scorm package), lessons and for example quizzes in the lessons.
But what is a lesson in scorm? A SCO? And how can i implement quizzes or other things?
Must i implement this myself in the user interface?

Comment: Can you make this more into a single specific question? For example, you could ask "How does SCORM handle navigation between lessons?" I've suggested that as an updated title for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Navigation between lessons can either be handled by the LMS outside the SCORM package, or it's possible to have multi-SCO packages where navigation happens within the package using a feature called sequencing. You can read about sequencing here: https://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/sequencing/